# MagicalRecord 2.3.2 MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion not updating right away

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

I am using (MagicalRecord, 2.3.2). I cannot figure out why using MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion on MR_defaultContext gives me "Updating fail!" and therefore i cannot update an entry right away.

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){
        if (success){
            NSLog(@"Updating success!");
        }
        else{ 
            NSLog(@"Updating fail!");
        }}];
```

MR_saveWithOptions:completion: is being called from MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion: and the bool hasChanges is NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i checked which thread the call stack is in, the issue in my case, was that the thread was nil:
{number = 14, name = (null)}

so i set it to the main thread and it fixed the update.